# Android: Phonegap 3.1.x fail to load geolocation plugin

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

We are using Phonegap 3.1.0-0.15.0 and the application chocked when trying to access location information.
Works fine in iOS however the App chock on Android

We are using:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(app.location.onSuccess, app.location.onError);
```

and we also tried:

```
var geo = cordova.require('cordova/plugin/geolocation');
geo.getCurrentPosition(app.location.onSuccess, app.location.onError);
```

The logcat mentioned the following:

```
Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail. at file:///android_asset/www/phonegap.js:1511
Uncaught module cordova/plugin/geolocation not found at file:///android_asset/www/phonegap.js:56
```

The plugin was added using:

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git
```

Are we doing something wrong ?

Thank you in advance

/Edwardo.

Comment: Do you have the cordova script included in your index.html?
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

Comment: Yes the cordova.js is included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own questions. I removed all the plugins manually and then add them (including the problematic geolocation plugin) using the following command:

```
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git
```

That solved my issue.

Edward.

Comment: Hey Edward, Was just trying this out but no luck getting even the gps icon showing up on the status bar let a lone getting a gps point. It just times out.
Any other tweaks or workarounds?
thanks!